# getting blank page when I tried to use slice function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a component in react to filter search results, I am parsing an array which contain the name, id and imgurl for each filter. But the filters' container should display only the limit number of filters and rest of the filters should add to a select (dropdown list).

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './Filters.css'
import MultipleSelectCheckmarks from '../MultipleSelectCheckmarks/MultipleSelectCheckmarks'

export default function Filters({filters,randomize,limit_items,onChange,space='100px'}) {
    const [activeFilters,setActiveFilter] = useState([]);
    const [deActiveFilters,setDeactiveFilter]= useState([]);

    // this updates the activeFilters and deActiveFilters arrays when filter-item change its state
    function setFilterState(id,state){
        if(state==0){
            setActiveFilter( activeFilters.filter((f)=>f!==id ));
            setDeactiveFilter( deActiveFilters=>[...deActiveFilters,id].sort((e,f)=>e-f) );
        }
        else{
            setDeactiveFilter( deActiveFilters.filter((f)=>f!==id ));
            setActiveFilter( activeFilters=>[...activeFilters,id].sort((e,f)=>e-f) );
        }
    }

    // render the filter-items
    let filterItm = function filter_item(name,img,position,count) {
        const [filterState,TougleState] = useState(0);  //store each filter item state
        const Tougle = event => {                        //create a event to triger when filter item get clicked. tougle the state and tougle filter-active class to add/remove styling
            if(filterState == 0) {                         
                TougleState(1);
                event.currentTarget.classList.add("filter-active");
                setFilterState(count, 1);
            }
            else {
                TougleState(0);
                event.currentTarget.classList.remove("filter-active");
                setFilterState(count,0);
            }
        }

        //render the filter item
        return(
    
            <div className="filter-item" onClick={Tougle} key={count} style={{transform:`translateX( calc( ${space} * ${position} ) )`}} id={'filter-'+count}>
                <div className="filter-item-icon" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${img})`}}></div>
                <p className="filter-item-name">{name}</p>
            </div>
    
        );
    }

    // run only once and set all the filters as deactive filters
    if(deActiveFilters.length == 0) {
        filters.map((e) => setDeactiveFilter(deActiveFilters => [...deActiveFilters, e.id].sort((e,f) => e-f)));
    }

    // if state change on any filter item change the order of items
    useEffect(() => {
        onChange(activeFilters);
        if (randomize) {              //if randomize is set to true then order as items randomly
            activeFilters.sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
            deActiveFilters.sort(() => Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
        }

        // set each filter item position
        let pos = 0;
        activeFilters.map((f) => {
            document.getElementById('filter-'+f).style.transform = `translateX( calc( 100px * ${pos++} ) )`;
        });
        deActiveFilters.map((f) => {
            document.getElementById('filter-'+f).style.transform = `translateX( calc( 100px * ${pos++} ) )`;
        });
        
    },[activeFilters,deActiveFilters]);

    //render the filter section
    const slicedfilters = filters.slice(0,limit_items); 
    //console.log(filters.slice(0,limit_items))
    //console.log(filters)
    return(
        <>
        <div className="filter-container">
            {
              
  //filters.map((e)=>filterItm(e.name,e.imgurl,e.id,e.id))
                 slicedfilters.map((e)=>filterItm(e.name,e.imgurl,e.id,e.id))    //this line is the problem
            }

            <div className="filter-item" style={{width:'120px',left:'unset',right:'0'}}>
                <MultipleSelectCheckmarks></MultipleSelectCheckmarks>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
        )

}
```

the filters array

```
const cardsjson= [
  {'id':0, 'name':'test0','imgurl':url},
  {'id':1,'name':'test1','imgurl':url},
  {'id':2,'name':'test2','imgurl':url},
  {'id':3,'name':'test3','imgurl':url},
  {'id':4,'name':'test4','imgurl':url},
  {'id':5,'name':'test5','imgurl':url},
  {'id':6,'name':'test6','imgurl':url},
  {'id':7,'name':'test7','imgurl':url},
  {'id':8,'name':'test8','imgurl':url},
  {'id':9,'name':'test9','imgurl':url},
  {'id':10,'name':'test10','imgurl':url},
  {'id':11,'name':'test1','imgurl':url},
  {'id':12,'name':'test2','imgurl':url},
  {'id':13,'name':'test3','imgurl':url},
  {'id':14,'name':'test4','imgurl':url},
  {'id':15,'name':'test5','imgurl':url},
  {'id':16,'name':'test6','imgurl':url},
  {'id':17,'name':'test7','imgurl':url},
];
```

```
    <Filters filters={cardsjson} randomize={false} onChange={getdata} limit_items={10} ></Filters>
```

My problem is when I'm tring to slice the filters (the array) and render the sliced filters I'm not getting any output.(I was able to console.log the sliced filters list) but if I removed the filters. Slice function and give the filters array to render, it works correctly.

I haven't much experience in this React library. I am so thankful If anyone can help me for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to render a limited number of filter items and then put the remaining items in a `dropdown` select. The issue might be related to how you're using the `slicedfilters` array within the map function.

On here:

```
slicedfilters.map((e) => filterItm(e.name, e.imgurl, e.id, e.id))
```

The problem here is that you're passing `e.id` as both the key and the last argument to `filterItm`, which could lead to unexpected behavior.

Try this one:

```
slicedfilters.map((e, index) =>
  filterItm(e.name, e.imgurl, index, e.id)
)
```

Now, `index` is being used as the last argument `(position)` for the `filterItm` function, and it's better suited for this purpose than `e.id`.

Additionally, ensure that the IDs of filter items are unique across the entire list, as React uses these IDs to efficiently update and re-render components. If there are duplicate IDs, you could face issues in component rendering and updates.

Finally, make sure the `space` prop you're passing is a valid CSS value (e.g., "100px") to avoid any potential rendering issues.

With these changes, your `slicedfilters.map` line should work as expected and render the limited number of filter items.

I hope this answer help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not yet solved that problem

Comment: After restarting the development server that problem solved. Also did some changes as you said.